# FB development - Upload a photo into user's profile

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, upload, facebook-php-sdk

Can you tell me what I do wrong. I use PHP. Try to upload the photo into users profile.. I get permissions and it works. But uploading doesn't work, I tryed many ways. So what do I do wrong?

```
  <?php

   include_once 'facebook.php';

       $facebook = new Facebook(array(
       'appId'  => 'ID',
       'secret' => 'SECRET',
       'cookie' => true,
       'domain' => 'DOMAIN',
       'fileUpload' => 'true'
       ));



      $session = $facebook->getSession();

      if (!$session) {

       $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'canvas' => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 1,
        'display' => 'page',
        'req_perms' => 'user_likes, publish_stream',
        'next' => 'NEXTURL'
   ));

      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";

    } else{


     try {

       $uid = $facebook->getUser();
       $me = $facebook->api('/me');
       $token = $session['access_token'];//here I get the token from the $session array
       $album_id = 'ALBUM ID';  /// what should I write here?

       //upload your photo
     $file= 'logo.png';
    $args = array(
       'message' => 'Photo from app',
    );
    $args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);

   $ch = curl_init();
  $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$album_id.'/photos?access_token='.$token;
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
   $data = curl_exec($ch);

  //returns the id of the photo you just uploaded
  print_r(json_decode($data,true));



  } catch(FacebookApiException $e){
  echo "Error:" . print_r($e, true);
  }
  }
  ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define 'does not work'. Are you seeing errors, warnings, other output

Comment: no errors.. First user clicks to "Go to app", then gives publish_stream permission and then the browser is redirected to the php page which is absolutely clear/empty. Can you tell me, what should I write in 1)  $album_id; 2) $file= 'logo.png'; <-- is it correct? should I mention here the URL of the photo? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the property fileUpload==true to the Facebook-Object:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'ID',
    'secret' => 'SECRET',
    'cookie' => true,
    'domain' => 'DOMAIN',
    'fileUpload' => true
));
```

UPDATE:

I always use this code to upload photos:

```
$photo= $facebook->api(array('method'=>'photos.upload',
            'caption'=>SOME_TEXT,
            'file'=>'@'.$file));
```

Comment: you mean, it's working now? Then please mark the question as answered.

Comment: No, I mean it's already added.. Can you tell me, what should I write in 1) $album_id; 2) $file= 'logo.png'; <-- is it correct? should I mention here the URL of the photo? thanks in advance

Comment: I updated my answer. With that code, the photos go to an album called "APP_NAME Photos". I think, $file is correct.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: couldn't open file "" thrown in /home/tychetec/public_html/app/facebook.php on line 622                                               now it shows this error

Comment: i edited again. did you replace my $img variable with your $file variable name. The error message looks like that.

Comment: Array ( [error] => Array ( [message] => (#240) The target_id references an inactive user [type] => OAuthException [code] => 240 ) )

Comment: target_id means the id of album?

Comment: I don't know what to mention in $album_id = '';

Comment: I think, target_id means the id of the user. Maybe your session has expired.

Comment: My friend, it created the album "upload photos" and uploaded it there with text "SOME_TEXT", thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$args = array('message' => $mess,
  );
  $args['image'] = '@' . realpath($file.".jpeg");


  $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
     try
     {
        if(!isset($_GET['a']))
            {
            $data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
            }
          //  echo "<br/>Image posted. <a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=".$data['id']."\" target=\"_blank\">Click here to view</a>. Thanks for using this application.";
      }
      catch(FacebookApiException $e)
      {
        var_dump($e);
      }
```

This is a direct excerpt from a working code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Upload');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($FILE_PATH);
$data = $facebook->api("/{$album_id}/photos", 'post', $args);
```

Note: if you want to create a new album name same as the app name and upload there then you have to use

```
$facebook->api("/me/photos", 'post', $args);
```